# Have Drop Down List With Non-Unique Values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list populated in code and the list displays everything as it should **BUT** if `Pink Water Buffalo` is selected from the drop down, the text displayed is `Yellow Snake`  Did I set something up incorrectly?  This is full syntax (and I have no selected index changed event for the drop down list that could cause err)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"] ?? HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      message.Visible = false;
      populateDDL();
    }
}

protected void populateDDL()
{
    var item = new List<ListItem>
    {
       new ListItem("", ""),
       new ListItem("Yellow Snake", "9"),,
       new ListItem("This item works", "12"),
       new ListItem("Pink Water Buffalo", "9"),
    };
    this.dropdownlistone.DataTextField = "Text";
    this.dropdownlistone.DataValueField = "Value";
    this.dropdownlistone.DataSource = item;
    this.dropdownlistone.DataBind();
}
```

**EDIT**
This is my asp that is used to create the drop down list

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlistone" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="278px"
                    AutoPostBack="true"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

**EDIT #2**
It's ugly and a lot of syntax if you have multiple drop down lists, but for me it wasn't a big deal.  What I did was added a .0, .1 etc and incremented up for each item in the drop down list.  Then used the `.Split` method to strip out only the relevant piece like so:

```
protected void populateDDL()
{
    var item = new List<ListItem>
    {
       new ListItem("", ""),
       new ListItem("Yellow Snake", "9.0"),,
       new ListItem("This item works", "12.1"),
       new ListItem("Pink Water Buffalo", "9.2"),
    };
    this.dropdownlistone.DataTextField = "Text";
    this.dropdownlistone.DataValueField = "Value";
    this.dropdownlistone.DataSource = item;
    this.dropdownlistone.DataBind();
}

String[] stringsplit = dropdownlistone.SelectedValue.ToString().Split('.');
String itemprice = stringsplit[0].Trim();
```

Comment: Where are you trying to fetch the value??

Comment: @RashidAbib works fine for me

Comment: Works fine for me too: are you sure you are not using two different dropdpwn lists ? (dropdownlistone and ddldropdownlistone)
The code that assigns the selecteditemtext value to the message label is missing, but it would be something like this:
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                message.Visible = false;
                populateDDL();
            }
            else
            {
                message.Visible = true;
                message.Text = dropdownlistone.SelectedItem.Text;
            }

Comment: You'll have to figure out a way to make the value unique for each item. Otherwise you will get unexpected results, possibly across different browsers.

Comment: @jrummell - any recommendations on a way to have products with same prices?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the value for "yellow Snake" and "Pink Water Buffalo" are both set to 9. "Yellow Snake" comes first in the list, so that is the one you are getting.

Comment: is their a way to have the same value for 2 items?  In reality this is a product database with product name and product price, so the same item can have the same price.

Comment: Their would need to be something unique about it, like an id. If you are trying to avoid going back to the server for price, concatenate the id and price and use that as the value, e.g.: `11:9.99`

Comment: I'd also recommend re-grabbing the product server side and repopulating the price in case the client tinkered with the values

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to figure out a way to make the value unique for each item. Otherwise you will get unexpected results, possibly across different browsers. A method I've used is combining the text and value with a pipe (`|`):

```
var item = new List<ListItem>
{
   new ListItem("", ""),
   new ListItem("Yellow Snake", "9|Yellow Snake"),
   new ListItem("This item works", "12|This item works"),
   new ListItem("Pink Water Buffalo", "9|Pink Water Buffalo"),
};
```

Then you can easily get the value by splitting it:

```
string value = dropdownlistone.SelectedValue.Split('|')[0];
```

I prefer the pipe as it's hardly ever used as a display value. Using a dot you might run into some issues if the text contains a dot, such as "Yellow Snakes are great, but green ones are the the best."